# How do I reapply for a position on the Jobs Board?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I applied for a position about 6 months ago, but it was filled before I could interview. That position is open again and I want to apply now.

Stack Overflow has other ideas: now when I click the apply button, it tells me I've already applied 6 months ago.

To make matters worse, I can't apply directly on the company's website because they just link back to Stack Overflow to apply.

I looked around in my settings to see if there was a way to delete applications or anything like that but I did not find anything relevant.

Is this a bug?

Comment: What is the exact date you applied? We only allow you to apply to the same position once every 6 months, so it'd only be a bug if that 6 months has actually passed already.

Comment: @animuson: "... but it was filled ..." so this is a *new* job – not the original one.

Comment: @RadLexus Unless on the company side they just reopened it, if it's possible.

Comment: @Walfrat: But I assume that in the mean time, the job offer was closed.

Comment: @RadLexus That doesn't matter. If the company used the same already-existing job listing then past applicants wouldn't be able to apply for 6 months. If they explicitly *wanted* past applicants to apply again, they could have easily copied it to a new listing and started fresh.

Comment: @animuson `If they explicitly wanted past applicants to apply again, they could have easily copied it to a new listing and started fresh.`  is it possible they didn't know about past applicants being blocked this way?

Comment: Is it also possible they took the easier path of clicking a "reopen job listing" button instead of tediously copying to a new listing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your application history I can only see two jobs that are currently running.

Of those jobs there is one that was applied to 6 months and a few hours ago. Assuming that is the job you're having trouble with then, yes, we have a bug.

The other job listing was applied to more recently and you won't be able to apply to it until some time next year.

If you can clarify which listing it is you're trying to apply to (by email to dward@stackoverflow.com if you want to keep it private) then I'll look into it further.

Comment: Wait, how did I apply to it again? I want to apply for their newly (re-)opened position but it says that I've already applied. There wasn't an action I could take that would let me apply to it again. There was a disabled "applied" element in the place of "apply now."

Comment: The employer re-used an existing job which effectively blocks anybody applying that applied within the 6 month window. If you can tell me which job it is you're trying to apply to I can a) determine whether we have a bug and b) get support to contact the employer to make sure they're aware that this is the case.